# Использование командной строки в PHP

Tags: php, ssh, консоль

Могу из php запустись команду как из командной строки?
На удалённом сервере.
Есть ли для этого функций в php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для удаленного сервера когда-то использовал вот эти функции [Функции SSH2](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.ssh2.php)

Там есть функция `ssh2_exec` для выполнение команды на удаленном сервере.

Выходит как-то так:

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, '/usr/local/bin/php -i');
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Функции запуска программ**

- **escapeshellarg** — Экранировать строку для того, чтобы она могла быть
  использована как аргумент командной строки
- **escapeshellcmd** — Экранировать метасимволы командной строки
- **exec** — Выполнить внешнюю программу
- **passthru** — Выполнить внешнюю программу и отобразить необработанный вывод
- **proc_close** — Завершить процесс, открытый proc_open и вернуть код возврата этого процесса
- **proc_get_status** — Получить информацию о процессе, открытом proc_open
- **proc_nice** — Изменить приоритет текущего процесса
- **proc_open** — Выполнить команду и открыть указатель на файл для ввода/вывода
- **proc_terminate** — Уничтожить процесс, открытый при помощи функции proc_open
- **shell_exec** — Выполнить команду через оболочку и вернуть вывод в виде строки
- **system** — Выполнить внешнюю программу и отобразить вывод

http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.exec.php